# Detecting large flat surfaces from .OBJ file (created from Kinect Fusion)

Tags: c#, kinect

I used Kinect Fusion to capture a scene and obtained an .OBJ file from it which contains the vertices, vertex normals as well as faces. I will then need to detect large flat surfaces based on these information, so that i may be able to detect planar surfaces such as walls or floor (as these are large flat surfaces). I've created my own data structure to store these information and coding it using C#. Does anyone know how i can find these flat surfaces?

Thanks you all so much in advance!

Comment: not sure if it's exactly what you're looking for, but perhaps [RANSAC plane detection](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=plane+detection+ransac&rlz=1C5CHFA_enGB524GB524&oq=plane+detection+ransac&aqs=chrome.0.57.3664j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) can help ?

Comment: Perhaps find combinations of vertices where the dot product between their normals is less than a threshold value? i.e. they are practically coplanar...

Comment: Wouldn't comparing each vertice be too complex? I tried comparing each vertice and the program just ran for more than 10mins. There are like 6digit lines of vertices. X_X I'm tasked to do this and left on my own right now.. Feeling so lost and confused......

Comment: Can you please tell me how you obtained the .obj file from kinect scene. I am looking for it.

Answer (score 1):

This won't be a full answer, but it might give you some ideas.

I personally would try some image processing algorithms. First one would be region growing. Second would be seed fill. I think that you would find some other better suited algorithms for segmentation too.

The key for this method to work is to consider face normal as the key feature. If two adjacent faces has similar enough (same) normal, you can consider them as a part of same surface.

Analogy here is, that you would replace pixel intensity, with face normal and then implement the image processing segmentation algorithm.

Maybe, but I doubt it would work for all cases, you can index the normals, thus assigning each normal it's index which would substitute the pixel intensity.

**EDIT:**

My idea is, that you take the scene snapshot and unwrap it, thus making it flat. From the unwrapped mesh, you can create "color map", by assigning each face color based on it's normal. Maybe you can just convert normal to color directly - normal (1,0,0) would be bright red, in RGB. This color map is in Graphics called normal texture, maybe you could get the normal texture from kinect directly.

Then in this color map you would find connected areas with similar/same color. This areas are parts of same flat surface, thus your desired floor or walls.

I have no prior experience with processing 3D data, so this is only my guess, but I think it should work. At least on paper. :)

I don't actually know which algorithms will work for unwrapping, or getting the normal texture. But it should give you some directions.

Comment: Erm jnovacho, sry if i sound retarded. But why is image processing used here when i'm dealing with a 3D environment? I'm still unfamiliar with all these, guess i chose a wrong project to do.. The .OBJ file which i get from Kinect Fusion consists of only the XYZ of the vertices, the XYZ of the vertice normal, and the face which tells me which 3 points makes up a face.